# How do you provide the best compatibility between SPDY HTTP 2.0 and HTTP 1.1?

Tags: http, spdy

With HTTP 2.0 being the proposed standard version of SPDY, how do you get the most compatibility with browsers between the protocols? Both will fall back to HTTP 1.1, but are there browsers that support only SPDY but not HTTP 2.0 or vis versa? Does SPDY fall back to HTTP 2.0 if SPDY support isn't available but HTTP 2.0 support is?